# Rails 3 - Refactor ruby conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring

I'd like to know if there is a simpler way to do these 2 conditions in ruby :

```
if params[:action] == 'index' || params[:action] == 'show'
```

and

```
if !(comment = (session[:my_params].include?(:comment) rescue nil)).nil?
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the first one, you could do:

```
if %w(index show).include?(params[:action])
```

The second should really be re-factored into two lines: assignment within a condition check is a code smell; there's never a reason for it.

If you're using Rails / ActiveSupport, you can take advantage of `Object#try`

```
comment = session[:my_params].try(:include?, :comment)
if comment
  # ... comment is in scope
end
```

Otherwise, you're left with something slightly clunkier:

```
comment = session[:my_params].include?(:comment) rescue nil
if comment
  # etc
```

Comment: what if session[:my_params] is nil?

Comment: this is the point, but is this a good approach to rescue nil as you suggested with : if (comment = (session[:my_params].include?(:comment) rescue nil))

Comment: Good point, Vlad. I've amended my answer. Assignment operations in a condition check is a code-smell. There's never a reason for it.

Comment: Rescue nil is one of the most used anti patterns

Comment: Well I won't use rescue nil in the future thanks to you :) I'll stick with the ActiveSupport Object#try which I find elegant

Comment: "There's never a good reason for it" ? That's a pretty strong statement that I would definitely not be comfortable making, even if I wasn't about to suggest that `while line = gets` is a good place to use it.

Comment: `while line = gets` is a _very_ specific use case. If you're reading from STDIN, go for it. Otherwise, it's a code smell that confuses new programmers and offers no syntactical benefit.

Answer (score 1):

1:

```
if ['index','show'].include? params[:action]
```

2:

```
if (comment = (session[:my_params].include?(:comment) rescue nil))
```

`!` and `.nil?` in second condition are redundant

But, really, you should not try to make everything as short as possible, the first thing to care about is how clear your code would be for other people. The second condition should look like:

```
if ( comment = (session[:my_params] && session[:my_params].include?(:comment) )
```

or even

```
comment = session[:my_params] && session[:my_params].include?(:comment)
if comment
```

Answer (score 0):

First one can be refractored like this:

```
if ['index', 'show'].include? params[:action]
```

or

```
if %w(index show).include? params[:action]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be faster than using an array and `include?`:

```
case params[:action]; when 'index', 'show'
   ...
end
```

The second one:

```
if comment = (session.fetch(:my_params, {}).include?(:comment))
```